# Error in react native app 'failed to call function, __fbbatchedbridge is undefined'

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. When I try to build the react native app in ios simulator im getting the following error

[failed to call function, __fbbatchedbridge is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcNBb.png)

`xcode version 12.4`
`react-native 0.61.5`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the __fbBatchedBridge error for different reasons (I accidentally deleted the reference to main.jsbundle from my Xcode project). I believe the error arises when React can't find the main.jsbundle file in your app's main bundle at runtime.

I was able to resolve it as follows:

Use the react-native command line to regenerate the main.jsbundle file (note that this command must be run from the root of your react native project).
$ react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
Add the generated main.jsbundle back into the Xcode project: File -> Add Files to Project. (After doing this you should verify that main.jsbundle appears in the files listed in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.)
Re-build and voila!